# hashbang is not refreshing the page correctly when hard refresh

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am building a backbone.js application with Rails 3. When I display the list of products and click on a product at the top I see url like

```
http://localhost:3010/#products/20
```

However when I hard refresh the page I do not see product information. On the server side instead of  a json request for product I see following

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-11 13:26:38 -0400
  Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
```

Here is my JavaScript code

```
$(function(){

  window.Product = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: { name: 'name missing' },
    urlRoot: '/products'
  });

  window.ProductsList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Product,
    url: '/products'
  });

  window.ProductViewForListing = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: $('#productTmplForListing').template(),
    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },
    className: 'product',
    render: function(){
      var fragment = $.tmpl(this.template, this.model.toJSON());
      $(this.el).html(fragment);
      return this;
    }
  });

  window.ProductViewForShow = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: $('#productTmplForShow').template(),
    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');
      this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
      var fragment = $.tmpl(this.template, this.model.toJSON());
      $(this.el).html(fragment);
      return this;
    }
  });

  window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#products'),
    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'showProduct');
      this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
      var targetElement = $('#products');
      var self = this;
      this.collection.each(function(product){
        var view = new ProductViewForListing({model: product}),
            fragment = view.render().el;
        self.el.append(fragment);
      });
    },
    showProduct: function(id){
      var product = new Product({id: id}), self = this;
      product.fetch({
        success: function(){
          var mainElement = self.el.closest('#main'),
              view = new ProductViewForShow({model: product});
          mainElement.find('#products').html('');
          self.el.append(view.render().el);
        },
        error: function(){ alert('error getting product details'); }
      });
      return false;
    }
  });

  window.products = new ProductsList();

  window.AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function(){
    },
    routes: {
      '': 'home',
      'products/:id': 'showProduct'
    },
    home: function(){
      var self = this;
      window.products.fetch({
        success: function(){
          self.appView = new AppView({ collection: window.products });
          self.appView.render();
        }
      });
    },
    showProduct: function(id){
      window.App.appView.showProduct(id);
    }
  });

  window.App = new window.AppRouter();
  Backbone.history.start({pushState: false});

});
```

Here is my index template

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="productTmplForListing">
  <a href="#products/${id}" data-id='${id}'>
    <img alt="${name}" class="productImage" height="190" src="/system/pictures/${id}/thumbnail/${picture_file_name}" width="190" />
  </a>
  <p class="productName">
    <a href="/products/${id}">
      ${name}
    </a>
  </p>
  <p class="productPrice">
    ${price}
  </p>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely getting a javascript error that says something like "undefined does not have a method called 'showProduct'", right?

the problem is the way you're creating the "window.App.AppView" in your router. you're only creating this object when the router hits the default route (the 'home' method). but when you are looking at the '#/products/20' hash fragment and you hit the refresh button in your browser, the home method on your router does not execute. only the showProduct route executes.

this should be easy to fix, though. you need to move the creation of "appView" outside of your router:

```
  window.AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function(){
    },
    routes: {
      '': 'home',
      'products/:id': 'showProduct'
    },
    home: function(){
      var self = this;
      window.products.fetch({
        success: function(){
          self.appView.render();
        }
      });
    },
    showProduct: function(id){
      window.App.appView.showProduct(id);
    }
  });

  window.App = new window.AppRouter();
  window.App.appView = new AppView({ collection: window.products });

  Backbone.history.start({pushState: false});
```

Now the "window.App.appView" will always be created when the page loads up and executes your javascript, no matter what route is executed.